# Arch Linux won't boot (only shows manufacturer's logo on screen)

Tags: boot, arch-linux

After selecting Arch on GRUB menu, it shows up the manufacturer's logo indefinitly.

[image]

It seems like even the Kernel is not loading because I do not see the log messages that I'd normally see while Arch is booting (which happens before the login screen on tty1).

I have triple boot with Arch, Ubuntu, and Kali. Arch is not booting, but both Ubuntu and Kali do boot (so, this is not a problem with BIOS or GRUB. GRUB is working fine). Arch doesn't boot since yesterday, when I moved 50 GB of files from my `~/studies` folder in Ubuntu to an external HD. The `~/studies` folder in Ubuntu was mounted at `~/studies` in Arch.

I think those events are somewhat related. Here is my `/etc/fstab` in Arch.

```
# Static information about the filesystems.
# See fstab(5) for details.

# <file system> <dir> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>
# /dev/sda5
UUID=2f838d2d-1066-4b25-ba12-4a3438583c99   /           ext4        rw,relatime 0 1

# mount other linux
UUID=8614db3a-6d74-459b-a763-b3b7e9184c25   /mnt/ubuntu ext4        auto,rw,nouser,noexec 0 
UUID=20b88a9e-a9b6-458c-b5be-348e85f687b2   /mnt/kali   ext4        auto,rw,nouser,noexec 0 0

# mount some folders
/mnt/ubuntu/home/ubuntu/studies /home/arch/studies none defaults,bind 0 0
```

I thought that If I commented the lines below "mount other Linux", then Arch would boot normally. That did not happen tough.

So, I booted into a live Arch ISO and ran 'arch-root' into my Arch. Then I ran `pacman -S linux && pacman -Syu`. After that, I restarted the computer but still Arch doesnot work.

I use Arch linux 95% of my time, so this is really messing up my workflow. Can somebody give me some help?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't boot"? What *happens* when you try to boot Arch? At which point does the process stop?

Comment: It just show the logo of the manufacturer. It seems like it doesn't even load the Kernel because the log messages that normally show up during the boot process are not appearing

Comment: @user1686 I have edited the question to make it clearer and to include the doubts you raised about the problem

Comment: I gave up on  that and ended up installing a new fresh Arch after 2 days trying